# How to manage Repository and UnitOfWork on top of JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, ddd-repositories

I'm wondering what would be the best way of implementing a UnitOfWork pattern on top of JDBC when using repository pattern.

I want to use UOW to commit or rollback commands from potentially multiple different repositories. So what I came up with is that the repositories get the connection they are going to execute commands on from the UOW object and let that manage committing or rolling it back.

Now the question is how shall the UOW manage connections? Shall it get one connection on start of a cycle and share it with all repositories when they call for a connection and at the end either commit or roll it back. Or shall it let the datasource manage the connections, and keep a reference to all the connections obtained in one session in order to be able to commit or rollback all of them?

Which way I use the best out of connection pooling and will have less trouble in managing connections?

Maybe its also worth noting that I use a single threaded approach, meaning a whole cycle (single UOW) is run on single thread and there is no fancy multithreading management required neither in UOW nor in repositories. However multiple cycles may run in parallel each on its own thread.